# Set default cell value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Other than the top row, which is a header, I'd like one column to always have a default value, ideally added when that row is not empty... so I don't have an infinite number of rows with just the default value.

I couldn't find a way to set default values at all - I *do not* want the user able to edit this.

Comment: Is this default value the same for *every* row? Or does it vary based on the contents of the row?

Answer (score 6):

You can fill that column with formula `=IF(D4="";"";"default value")`, assuming you're in row 4 and column D will be filled in later on. 
(Use `=IF(D4="","","default value")`
if your version of Excel separates function arguments with commas.)

Translation:

- If the row 4 is not filled in, then the result is blank so nothing is shown.
- If the row 4 is filled and the user has entered a value in column D, then your default value is shown.
- The user can fill in any other value instead of this formula, thereby simply overwriting the formula which isn't needed anymore anyway.
- You can protect the column if you don't want the user to overwrite your default value.

Comment: what if we want to apply this formula on whole column??

Answer (score -1):

the hard but more convenient way is to give the default value  in the first case and then copy them to all other vertical cells by using the cursor at the right hand corner till there is a cross and pull it down to the last cell. this is useful only in relatively small samples.
very useful if you are calculating in the cell by applying a formula in the first cell.
Smsv